# Lex yacc changing buffer

Tags: yacc, lex

Flex provides a mechanism for creating and switching between multiple input buffers. An input buffer is created by using: yy_creat_buffer and gives the possibility to switch input stream by using yy_switch_buffer.

The problem is lex does not implement a solution like that.

you can find more [in the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there no similar solution in lex, and if any one knows one please please give it to us.

The only possibility is that you redefine`yywrap()`,which is called whenever Lex reaches an end-of-file.

In this case, you should provide a `yywrap()` which arranges for new input and returns 0. This instructs Lex to continue processing. The default yywrap always returns 1(no added input).